# Is there a way to directly edit files on a server?

Tags: ide

Is there anyway to directly code on a server, meaning you open the file from the server and save it there?

Or is there any method faster than traditional ftp that automatically syncs to the server when you save locally?

Comment: Use SVN Tortoise at server side. And whenever you change the code commit it. It will reflect on server side file.

Comment: Really depends on how much control you have over the server. Are we talking a hosted web server, a server you have full rights to, a server you can SSH into?

Comment: godaddy as basic as you can get. I just want to host some js files for my browser extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SVN is a good option.
Read this: [Combined SVN FTP system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71163/combined-svn-ftp-system)

Comment: @harry: i wouldn't have bothered to answer, if you had made your comment an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're just talking about text files then some text editors support this, e.g. [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html), which can open and save directly to/from FTP/SFTP etc.